# Kind with entities that belongs to different Kind of parents

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In my GAE app I'd like to implement a special entity, a child entity that can be connected to different types of parents. It's an `Attachment`. I'd like to put this items into same entity group, use ancestor queries, etc.

There could be:

```
article1 with Key('Article', 1)
attach1 with Key(article1, 'Attach', 1)
attach2 with Key(article1, 'Attach', 2)

task1 with Key('Task', 1)
attach3 with Key(task1, 'Attach', 1)
```

As you see, it's same Entity Kind (`Attach`) that have parent keys from different Kind of parents (`Article` and `Task`).

I didn't try such relations before, and not sure if it's going to work. Is it ok for GAE  datastore? or maybe it's just a bad practice and architectural flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore just uses a Key to define an entity group, so it doesn't mind if those keys relate to different kinds.

However, if you want to `get()` an entity, you will need to know its ancestor so you can form the key 'path'.  So, following your example (in Java), if you want to `get()` **attach3**, you need to know that its ancestor (task1) is of Kind Task:

```
Key ancestorKey = KeyFactory.create("Task", 1); // need to know ancestor is a Task
Key attach3Key = KeyFactory.create(ancestorKey, "Attach", 3);
Entity attach3 = datastore.get(attach3Key);
```

...whereas if you want to retrieve **attach1**:

```
Key ancestorKey = KeyFactory.create("Article", 1); // here ancestor is an Article
Key attach1Key = KeyFactory.create(ancestorKey, "Attach", 1);
Entity attach1 = datastore.get(attach1Key);
```

You might like to have a think about what sort of transactions, queries and fetches your application needs to provide to understand if this will work for you.

Comment: Ok, so it's totally not a problem to use different kinds of parents? great!

Comment: In fact the 'parent' doesn't even need to exist, it's literally just a Key.